# REST API to get user profile information for multiple users?

Tags: 2013, javascript, rest, user-profile

I've been following [this MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn790354.aspx) on using REST api to retrieve user profile and social data for either the current user or an specific user. We are running 2013 on prem so for example I might call this:

```
https://<site>/_api/sp.userprofiles.peoplemanager/getfollowersfor(@v)?@v='<domain\user>'&$select=DisplayName
```

If I want to get the followers for two different users is there a way to do that with one call or do I need to make a call for each person?

I'm trying to do an in-browser, client side visualization of following/followers and will need to retrieve information about several people.

Is there a way to retrieve multiple user's information at once using REST calls?

Should I think about using JSOM or something else instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the REST API getFollowersFor (your example above), you will need to make a HTTP GET request once per user ID. To be specific, the getFollowersFor API call only accepts one user account as a parameter.

SharePoint online has REST API batching, which allows you to construct multiple HTTP requests into one request.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/office/dn903506.aspx

CSOM/JSOM will allow you to make multiple requests from a single web service call.  This will probably be the best solution, depending on your requirements.
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/18580.sharepoint-2013-how-to-get-following-and-followers-of-user-by-using-jsom-or-javascript.aspx

Comment: Thank you. The CSOM/JSOM example is almost exactly what I need. I'm also trying to combine the ExtendedManagers Manager, Peers, DirectReports, ExtendedReports info, which isn't part of social (evidently). Can you point me to the documentation for that?